# How to make Core Blazor CSS isolation work?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the **BadgeDemoPage** component represented with the following files:

[image]

Unfortunately, these styles from `BadgeDemoPage.razor.css` has not been applied.

Of course, I have read the [ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0) documentation. As far as I have understood, It is enough just to specify the correct name of files and actual styles:

> To define component-specific styles, create a `.razor.css` file
> matching the name of the `.razor` file for the component in the same
> folder. The `.razor.css` file is a scoped CSS file.
>
> For an `Example` component in an `Example.razor` file, create a file
> alongside the component named `Example.razor.css`. The
> `Example.razor.css` file must reside in the same folder as the Example
> component (`Example.razor`). The `"Example"` base name of the file is
> not case-sensitive.

Also, my Visual Studio displays the **BadgeDemoPage.razor.css** as child file in relation to **BadgeDemoPage.razor**. It means, the file naming is correct.

[image]

Some additional condition to make it work?

### Appendix

#### index.html

I have added also 2 global stylesheets: `Primer.css` and `CommonRequirements.css`. They are being applied correctly but this question is focused on isolated styles of specific components.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>Demos</title>

  <base href="/" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Primer.css"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/CommonRequirements.css"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blazor.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <svg class="loading-progress">
      <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
      <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
    </svg>
    <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
  </div>
  
  <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

#### Browser Output

[image]

Comment: Multiple questions.. Let's take it one by one. You have the wrong version when running the app.. Try to: "Configure Startup Projects". Currently you have set Package as your startup project (it is bolt in solution explorer)

Comment: Browers cache static files. Index.html is assumed to be static. Clear the browsers cache for it to load the new Index page.

Comment: @Alamakanambra Thank you for the comment! I have set the "Demos" as the startup project. When I launched the `http` preset, the HTML page content was up-to-date, with `CommonRequirements.css` and `Primer.css`. However, the isolation is still does not work.

Comment: Did you uncomment the code as the browser screenshot is suggesting? Because you need to link this `Demos.styles.css` in your code, that's the place where "isolated" css lives.

Comment: @Alamakanambra Sorry about I could not take the time for this problem for a while. I have updated the question will actual information only. The file `Demos.styles.css` is not actual anymore. There is only 1 target left: make styles from `BadgeDemoPage.razor.css` display.

Comment: You still don't have the css isolation file referenced in your index.html https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling . `<link href="{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @Alamakanambra Would you please to write the answer? I'll give you the reputation prize. And please, mention about limitations like "the isolation is not applied to the components from external packages even used in page with isolated styles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alamakanambra said in the comment, you NEED to add in the head of the generated html documents to make blazor isolation work.

```
<link href="{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is done in

- the index.html in maui blazor app,
- In the _host.html in pre asp.net8 blazor apps.
- in the App.razor file in .net8 if I'm not mistaken.

BEWARE of some limitation that caused me some headaches: you can't override children class.
Considering the following layout

```
<RazorParent>
  <RazorChild>
  </RazorChild>
</RazorParent>
```

Any styling of a css class in the child, must be declared in RazorChild.razor.css

If you put in **RazorParent.razor.css**

```
.somechildclass{
   color:red !important;
}
```

and in **RazorChild.razor.css**

```
.somechildclass{
   color:#fff;
}
```

When you load something with RazorParent, the color will be white, even if, in my humble opinion, it feels like it should be red.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You have written the great answer, but I because I have promised to give the reputation prize to Alamakanambra in the comments earlier, I have to keep my promise. I am sorry, but please let me to reward you be upvote and accepting of the answer this time.

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in comments, the issue was the lack of reference of the isolation file in the `index.html` file. Described in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling).

```html
<link href="{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note that the isolated css is respected "per component". CSS defined in parent component `.css` file will have no effect in child components. This comes from the fact that every component receives scope identifier (`<h1 b-3xxtam6d07>`) and every class is only per that identifier.

```css
h1[b-3xxtam6d07] {
    color: brown;
}
```

Your child component has different identifier - which is also true for components from external packages.

(for more info, the same [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling) )